# Azure Policy to deny traffic if source address prefixes are not within the private range

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying to modify an existing custom policy which I obtained from github. The goal is to not allow users to RDP from public IP addresses. The ARM template needs to support only private ranges. Here is the code:

```
    {
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules"
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/access",
              "equals": "Allow"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/direction",
              "equals": "Inbound"
            },
            {
              "anyOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                  "equals": "*"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                  "equals": "3389"
                },
                {
                  "value": "[if(and(not(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'))), contains(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'),'-')), and(lessOrEquals(int(first(split(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'), '-'))),3389),greaterOrEquals(int(last(split(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'), '-'))),3389)), 'false')]",
                  "equals": "true"
                },
                {
                  "count": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                    "where": {
                      "value": "[if(and(not(empty(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')))), contains(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')),'-')), and(lessOrEquals(int(first(split(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')), '-'))),3389),greaterOrEquals(int(last(split(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')), '-'))),3389)) , 'false')]",
                      "equals": "true"
                    }
                  },
                  "greater": 0
                },
                {
                  "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                    "notEquals": "*"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                    "notEquals": "3389"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "anyOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix",
                  "equals": "*"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix",
                  "equals": "Internet"
                },
                {
                  "value": "[or(ipRangeContains('10.0.0.0/8', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')),ipRangeContains('172.16.0.0/12', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')),ipRangeContains('192.168.0.0/16', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')))]",
                  "equals": false
                },
                {
                  "count": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                    "where": {
                      "value": "[or(ipRangeContains('10.0.0.0/8', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))),ipRangeContains('172.16.0.0/12', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))),ipRangeContains('192.168.0.0/16', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))))]",
                      "equals": false
                    }
                  },
                  "greater": 0
                },
                {
                  "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                    "notEquals": "*"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                    "notEquals": "Internet"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

The following section works well. It does not allow me to add IP addresses other than private IP ranges. So policy denies creation of NSG rule with MY PUBLIC IP address.

```
{
                      "value": "[or(ipRangeContains('10.0.0.0/8', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')),ipRangeContains('172.16.0.0/12', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')),ipRangeContains('192.168.0.0/16', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')))]",
                      "equals": false
                    }
```

The next section throws an error

```
{
                  "count": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                    "where": {
                      "value": "[or(ipRangeContains('10.0.0.0/8', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))),ipRangeContains('172.16.0.0/12', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))),ipRangeContains('192.168.0.0/16', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))))]",
                      "equals": false
                    }
                  },
                  "greater": 0
                }
```

So, if I enter multiple Private IP's separated by comma, when creating NSG for SourceAddress, I get the following error:

```
The inner error is 'The policy language function 'ipRangeContains' has encountered one or more invalid IP Ranges: '"10.0.0.0/8",null'. IP Ranges can be specified in CIDR notation, single IP address or a range with start and end addresses separated with a '-'. Ranges that mix between IPv4 and IPv6 and ranges that don't include any addresses are not allowed.'.
```

Any ideas/suggestions on fixing this error will be great help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include logic for not empty source IP fields and check them to not match * and Internet.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules"
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/access",
              "equals": "Allow"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/direction",
              "equals": "Inbound"
            },
            {
              "anyOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                  "equals": "*"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                  "equals": "3389"
                },
                {
                  "value": "[if(and(not(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'))), contains(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'),'-')), and(lessOrEquals(int(first(split(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'), '-'))),3389),greaterOrEquals(int(last(split(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'), '-'))),3389)), 'false')]",
                  "equals": "true"
                },
                {
                  "count": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                    "where": {
                      "value": "[if(and(not(empty(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')))), contains(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')),'-')), and(lessOrEquals(int(first(split(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')), '-'))),3389),greaterOrEquals(int(last(split(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')), '-'))),3389)) , 'false')]",
                      "equals": "true"
                    }
                  },
                  "greater": 0
                },
                {
                  "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                    "notEquals": "*"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                    "notEquals": "3389"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "anyOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix",
                  "equals": "*"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix",
                  "equals": "Internet"
                },
                {
                  "value": "[if(and(not(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix'))),not(contains(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix'),'*')),not(contains(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix'),'Internet'))),not(or(ipRangeContains('10.0.0.0/8', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')),ipRangeContains('172.16.0.0/12', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')),ipRangeContains('192.168.0.0/16', field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefix')))),'false')]",
                  "equals": true
                },
                {
                  "count": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                    "where": {
                      "value": "[or(ipRangeContains('10.0.0.0/8', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))),ipRangeContains('172.16.0.0/12', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))),ipRangeContains('192.168.0.0/16', first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]'))))]",
                      "equals": false
                    }
                  },
                  "greater": 0
                },
                {
                  "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                    "notEquals": "*"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "not": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/sourceAddressPrefixes[*]",
                    "notEquals": "Internet"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```